# Transform TorusGeometry to lay on Coplanar Points

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, transformation, matrix-multiplication

I have a three.js scene with 3 coplanar points. I also have 1 torus geometry. I would like to transform the torus geometry so that it lays as if it is sitting on the coplanar points. How would I do this in three.js?

This [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hertz-87ckg) sets up the scenario.

[image]

Comment: PYou can make vectors that point from and to the coplanar points (subtract the points from one another) then take the cross product of two of those vectors to give you a vector that points up from the plane. 

Then you can use that up vector (depending on the model orientation of the torus) to set the rotation of torus to orient correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, then you can achieve it, using `.lookAt()`, `THREE.Plane()` and its `.normal` property:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 2.5;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
// controls.autoRotate = true;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x888888);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfdfcf0, 1);
directionalLight.position.set(10, 10, 10);
scene.add(directionalLight);

renderer.setClearColor("#000000");
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const positionFrom = (latitude, longitude, radius) => {
  const phi = (90 - latitude) * (Math.PI / 180);
  const theta = (longitude + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);
  const x = -(radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta));
  const z = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
  const y = radius * Math.cos(phi);
  return [x, y, z];
};
const points = [
  ["80.9721379481747", "-93.2620712575402"],
  ["84.899876841301", "-15.8849444339213"],
  ["-80.9618531929051", "81.2440393281301"]
];
const pts = [];
points.forEach(([lat, long]) => {
  const position = positionFrom(lat, long, 1);
  const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff
  });
  const earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
  earth.position.set(...position);
  scene.add(earth);
  pts.push(earth.position);
});

const plane = new THREE.Plane();
plane.setFromCoplanarPoints(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2]);
const helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper(plane, 1, 0x00ff00);
const torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(0.5, 0.1, 3, 100);
const torusMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00e1ff
});
const torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
torus.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(torus.position, plane.normal));
scene.add(helper);
scene.add(torus);

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```